# Expected value of geometric Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-pde

So everyone knows that the expected value of GBM is given by:

$X_0 \exp(\mu t)$

My question is that what does this say about such stochastic processes? Since $X_0$ and $\mu$ are within "my control" to choose, could I not always just manipulate this expression to get the expected value I want? Therefore, are these processes "really" stochastic?

Comment: That's only the expected value; once you've taken the expected value you have marginalized all the randomness away. There are still fluctuations around that mean value, and they are quite important whenever $\sigma W_t$ is comparable to $(\mu-\sigma^2/2)t$ (which will always happen sometimes, even if $\sigma \ll \mu$). Also, I think you're wrong about the expected value but I would need to check it over again. (The expected value is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} t} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp((\mu-\sigma^2/2)t+\sigma x) e^{-x^2/2t} dx$, I'm just not 100% sure on what that is without some computation.)

Comment: @Ian Okay, thank you. But, does it say something that my choosing these parameters, I can still "direct" this stochastic process.

Comment: Sure, although in applications these are usually given, not tunable.

Comment: @Ian Okay, understood, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If $\{B_t:t\in\mathbb R_+\}$ is a standard Brownian motion, then $$X_t := X_0\exp\left(\left(\mu-\frac12\sigma^2\right)t+\sigma B_t\right) $$ (where $X_0$, $\mu$, and $\sigma$ are constants) defines a geometric Brownian motion. 
It is clear that if $X_0=0$ then $X_t$ is identically zero, and similarly if $\sigma=0$ then $X_t = X_0 e^{\mu t}$ with probability one. Assuming that $X_0\ne 0$ and $\sigma>0$, though, $X_t$ has log-normal distribution with
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X_t] &= X_0 e^{\mu t},\\
\operatorname{Var}(X_t) &= X_0^2 e^{2\mu t}\left(e^{\sigma^2 t} -1\right).
\end{align}
So $X=\{X_t:t\in\mathbb R_+\}$ is a collection of random variables indexed by a totally ordered set, and indeed is a stochastic process. The limiting behavior of $X_t$ is determined by the value of the parameters, however. From the law of the iterated logarithm
$$\mathbb P\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{B_t}{\sqrt{2t\log\log t}}=1\right)=1, $$
and so almost sure convergence of $X_t$ is determined by the $\left(\mu-\frac12\sigma^2\right)t$ term:

- If $\left(\mu-\frac12\sigma^2\right)>0$, then $\lim_{t\to\infty} \left(\mu-\frac12\sigma^2\right)t=\infty$ and so $X_t\stackrel{\mathrm{a.s.}}\longrightarrow\infty$.
- If $\left(\mu-\frac12\sigma^2\right)<0$, then $\lim_{t\to\infty} \left(\mu-\frac12\sigma^2\right)t=0$ and so $X_t\stackrel{\mathrm{a.s.}}\longrightarrow0$.
- If $\left(\mu-\frac12\sigma^2\right)=0$, then $X_t$ does not converge almost surely (since $B_t$ does not). Also, this condition implies that $X_t$ is a martingale (verifying this is a good exercise).

Comment: Wow! That is a very detailed and thoughtful answer. Thank you.

Comment: @ThomasMoore You're welcome. Glad I could help.